# How to remove website require validation magento on new_action

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, products-management, validation, multi-website

How do I remove the validation for 'website required' before saving a new product in Magento? I have a script that auto assigns the website based on logic for on save_before, but the validation fires for new products before my script can run.

I'm looking on how to shut this off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not required to assign a website when creating a product. This message is probably coming from a custom module, search for the message to find it and turn it off.

It is either a customization of the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Websites` block that adds client side validation or another observer for `catalog_product_save_before` or a similar event.